# Changing theme folder name disrupts widgets

Tags: themes, widgets

I am trying to change name of theme folder. Steps i am following are...

1. upload backup files
2. rename theme folder name on server
3. in xml database file (demo content file of theme), find '/old-folder-name/' and replace all with '/new-folder-name/' using text editor.

The problem is most of the widgets stop working / displaying.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Did you rename the theme in the style.css file?

Comment: @NathanielFlick yes. renamed theme name in style.css but that did not work.

Comment: Go back to Appearance/Themes and activate another theme then the one you want again. Does it now show?

Comment: @NathanielFlick tried that and that did not work. I don't understand what theme folder name has to do with widgets. All widgets disappear after changing folder name.

Comment: The widgets shouldn't have anything to do with the theme/folder name, which is why you need to solve that problem first. Hard to see what's going on without being able to see your theme/file structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some themes save the recent sidebar widgets settings amongst other theme settings in wp_options as **theme_mods_mynewtheme** (assuming *mynewtheme* is your new theme folder name).

If you lost some settings (including widget settings), you can copy/paste the option_value contents of **theme_mods_myoldtheme** into **theme_mods_mynewtheme**. That may help or at least restore some theme settings. However, that might not restore your sidebar settings (theme-specific case, not general).

[image]

In general, if you haven't re-activated your theme under Appearance > Themes, you can save your old sidebar_settings first and re-insert them in the database after you reactivated your new theme:

1. `SELECT * FROM wp_options where option_name = 'sidebars_widgets'`
2. Copy the entire contents of **option_value**
3. Re-activate your theme under Appearance > Themes
4. Refresh the query from step 1
5. Paste what you copied from step 2 into **option_value**

Edit: In case you don't have database access, you can programatically (somehow ugly approach) use the functions **get_option** and **update_option** to do the above. You can use [maybe_serialize](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/maybe_serialize) to serialize what you get from get_option and pass using [maybe_unserialize](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/maybe_unserialize) to **update_option**.